# how can I redirect my network traffic through tor network

Tags: c#, tor

I have made a app that will send data to a server but due to confidentiality of the data of my clients , it needs to be anonymous so I thought of using TOR network and I know TOR doesn't work with HTTP it require SOCKS . How can I use this in my application to send data, also it would not be feasible that my clients would be having TOR application installed on client machine . Is there any way to achieve what I want?
thanks

Comment: perhaps this can help -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378642(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: but how can I route my traffic through TOR using this?

Comment: tor won't magically make the data you're sending anonymous.  is the issue of seeing where the data comes from to your server, or stuff in the content?  if it's the content  you'll have to build something that sanitizes the data before you send it.

Comment: actually the clients need to make sure that the data is sent in anonymous way , that is it should not be track-able,I can encrypt the data I am sending but how can I make the identities of server and client not traceable or how can I use P2P for this

Comment: This can you help: https://www.wikihow.com/Route-All-Network-Traffic-Through-the-Tor-Network